# Codeigniter form validation for EDIT

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to figure out this problem, But I am not being able to.

Say I have a category CRUD. 
When creating the category, I can successfully use the validation, however while doing the edit, I have this issue.

I need to load the edit form for a particular ID say `category/edit/4` so that I could pre populate the form with the category name. I could use a redirect as `redirect(base_url().'admin/category/edit/'.$id)` but then I wont be able to use `validation_errors()` . I could use `flashdata` to display errors but is there any other option to do it with `views` and `validation_errors()` .

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    //process the form data 

    }else{
        $data['subview'] = 'admin/category/edit';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For edit you can do it like this

Controller

```
function edit()
{
    $id =   $this->uri->segment(3);

    if($post = $this->input->post()){
        $this->form_validation->rule('name','Name','required');
        .
        .
        .

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            // update query
        }else{
            $row    =   $this->my_model->get_row($id);
            $data['row']    =   $row;
            $this->load->view('edit_form',$data);           
        }
    }else{

        $row    =   $this->my_model->get_row($id);
        $data['row']    =   $row;
        $this->load->view('edit_form',$data);
    }
}
```